# zipping a folder using ant

Tags: ant

I want this folder structure to be zipped as it is-

[image]

Right now I am doing these steps-

1. Moving files other than folders to "Temp" folder.
2. Moving Folder1 to "Temp" folder.
3. Zipping Temp.
4. Deleting "Temp folder".

Is this the correct approach or is there any simple/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to move the files before zipping them.

```
<zip destfile="test.zip" basedir="src_dir" includes="**/*"/>
```

If you had a more challenging selection to make than `**/*`, e.g. include and exclude specific files selectively, then you could achieve that with one or more filesets (or zipfilesets) within the zip element.

Here is the dir structure, including build.xml:

```
$ find .
.
./build.xml
./src_dir
./src_dir/Document.txt
./src_dir/Document2.txt
./src_dir/Document3.xml
./src_dir/Folder1
```

Here is the zip file created:

```
$ jar tvf test.zip
     0 Fri Jul 20 08:36:06 GMT 2012 Folder1/
     0 Fri Jul 20 08:36:26 GMT 2012 Document.txt
     0 Fri Jul 20 08:36:12 GMT 2012 Document2.txt
     0 Fri Jul 20 08:36:18 GMT 2012 Document3.xml
```